# Restricting dual app featured mobile user to run only single application

Tags: java, android, duplicates, mirror

I am having a Android application,  which I want to restrict the user to run only single application in his Android mobile, even though he has dual app installation feature in his mobile i want to restrict the user to install and run only one same application. TIA

Comment: Can you give example of what is `dual app installation feature`. Manufacturer/device/app name or a step by step behavior to enable on [fill in name]  phone.

Comment: I don't think it is possible as this functionality is provided by OS it self. Is there any other app doing this?

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest add

```
<activity
    ....
    android:launchMode="singleInstance">
```

to your `activitivy`

Comment: Not working, successfully installing dual apps. Any other programatic logic. TIA